# Feature Flagging in Production for a non partner client. Possible?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

This is more of a generic question about feature flagging in Salesforce. Our company currently uses LaunchDarkly for other applications, we are under the investigating process to see if it will work for Salesforce.

The goal: Enable new features/improvements for only a set of clients in our production environment so it could be tested by them.

After a quick dive into the LaunchDarkly documentation, looks like the only way to accomplish this is by setting up flags within out APEX code.

The issue: It only works for APEX. What about page layouts, Flows, FLS, etc?

I found a module within Trailhead called ["Manage Your Features Unit"](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/appexchange_licensing/appexchange_licensing_features?trail_id=isv_developer_beginner).

But as per SF documentation: "We offer feature parameters to AppExchange partners exclusively. Log a support case in the Salesforce Partner Community when you’re ready to try them out."

We are not a SF partner.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished for our internal/community users? Has anyone used LaunchDarkly with SF? Any other tool(s)?

I wonder if we are the only ones trying this :)

I'm really open for best practices and ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking a broad, opinion-based question - please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). A broad answer to your question is that a) it depends and b) it really depends. Feature flags for Apex code components are common and can be implemented via settings, metadata, custom objects and so on.   Non-code entities such as page layouts have options that achieve similar outcome but without using feature flags. Lots of Q&As here on these topics, do a search.

Comment: Hi @identigral, I did search here. Since we are not partners, and as per SF this is a feature used mostly by partner while using AppExchange, I wasn't able to find a similar post. I was also wondering if anybody uses LaunchDarkly as well. If you have any link, I would appreciate. Txs.

Comment: Feature Management App (FMA) is an AppExchange/packaged app service. It's not applicable to your use case and you won't be able to use it. No idea about Launch Darkly. https://github.com/pgonzaleznetwork/salesforce-feature-flags is an example of a native implementation that uses various options mentioned in our comment